# Override class for plugin in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, plugins, lucene

I'm working on a `ElasticSearch` plugin to retrieve the total frequency of a searched term. I've already created a maven project and successfully deployed my test plugin into `ElasticSearch` but I have no idea how to write/override a function to perform this task.

I have found out that there is a [getTotalTermFreq()](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.2.2/org/elasticsearch/index/similarity/ScriptedSimilarity.Term.html#getTotalTermFreq%2D%2D) function in `org.elasticsearch.index.similarity.ScriptedSimilarity.Term` class/object which returns the total number of occurrences of this term in the index, or -1 if this statistic is not available. But, I have no idea how to use this function in the plugin!

I already tried looking in to other open source plugins available on github but couldn't find anything useful or I can say I didn't understand that much because of my no-experience in Java.

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.